# Где физически находится база данных SQLite в Android?

Tags: android, sqlite

Подскажите, пожалуйста, где физически находится база данных SQLite в Android? Хочу выгрузить посмотреть что в ней находится, а найти не могу. Ниже скриншот.
[image: Android]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

По умолчанию находится в каталоге:

```
/data/data/{my.app.domain}/databases/
```

Comment: На самом деле, далеко не факт, что именно там. она лежит там, куда вы ее положили, когда создавали.

Comment: Она может (и должна, кстати) лежать туда куда указывает метод `Context.getDatabasePath()` - программист может переопределить этот метод

Comment: Кстати без рут доступа глянуть на нее не получится