# Как узнать путь к SqlLite базе данных в Android?

Tags: java, android, android-sdk, sqlite

Как узнать где находится находится бд SqlLite в Android

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Передаём гуглу строку

> [android get path to database](https://www.google.ru/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=android%20get%20path%20to%20database)

2. Получаем [ответ](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29862723/3212712):

   ```
   context.getDatabasePath(YourDbName).getAbsolutePath();
   ```

---

метод

> Context.getDatabasePath(String YourDbName)

возвращает путь к стандартному месту хранения БД приложения, коий выглядит так:

```
//data/data/<Your-Application-Package-Name>/databases/<your-database-name>
```

---

В `AS`, на эмуляторе, к файлу можно попасть через `DeviceMonitor` -> `File exprorer`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: я наверное задал вопрос неправильно, я хотел бы узнать она локальна гдето хранится или нет?

Comment: я смотрел тут http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/417010/ но не понял

Comment: @java, а что именно вы не поняли? То, что без рута её через файловый менеджер не достать?

Comment: этот файловый менеджер в телефоне должен быть или в студио?

Comment: просто я прочитал что Наличие БД в виртуальном девайсе через Eclipse можно посмотреть так:
Меню Window->Show View->Other->Android->File Explorer. Далее по пути data/data/my.database.work3/databases, а как это можно в студио сделать?

Comment: @java, на студии не пробовал, а на эклипс с эмулятором да, так можно. В AS, похоже, только через командную строку. Так что проще прямо через файловый мэнеджер эмулятора.

Comment: Ещё вам может пригодиться способ копирования файла DB в незакрутую память телефона: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/459405/17609

Comment: Эмулятор использую Genymoion, а как узнать есть там рут или нет, приложение SuperUser есть обычно оно только на тех где есть рут если я правильно понимаю, и file manager есть, но куда там нужно зайти подскажите пожалуйста

Comment: @java, Genymoion да, рутованный. Засим через файл-менеджер идите по пути из конца моего ответа.

Comment: если я вас правильно понял то путь это //data/data/<Your-Application-Package-Name>/databases/<your-database-name> и его надо написать в эмуляторе кудато или как?

Comment: @java, надо пройти по этим папкам в файловом мэнеджере. Кстати, в AS таки есть доступ к файлам, см. обновлённый ответ.

Comment: спасибо большое вам)))))

Comment: @java, помимо "спасибо" хорошим тоном, также, считается тут за ответы/вопросы "голосовать" стрелочками слева от них. За это даже ачивки тут дают)

Comment: ок, я не знал сорри), просто перевести в положение от 0 к 1?

Comment: @java, да, всё верно)

Comment: ок, буду знать на будущее))