# Обновление импортированной бд SQLite в андроид

Tags: java, android, sqlite

Суть в том, что я постоянно вношу изменения в базу данных, но когда пересобираю проект, приложение работает со старой версией, приходиться удалять приложение с устройства и по новой  его устанавливать. Есть способ обновления импортированой базы?

Comment: Я делаю так: при установке приложения у меня создается/копируется база данных. В этот момент в Preferences сохраняю код приложения. Если я нее сам позже внес изменения, то так же как и у вас мне ее нужно обновить. Я меняю код приложения и при открытии главной активности делаю проверку текущего кода и сохраненного, если они не совпадают, я копирую/обновляю БД. Ну и снова сохраняю в настройках новый код.

Comment: Я не меняю код я только инфу в бд добавляю надо что бы старая версия удалялось, а новая ставилась.

Comment: для этого код приложения и используется. Увеличивайте его номер - это будет флагом, что нужно обновить БД или показать окно обновления или еще что.

Comment: Если лень писать код, который следит за актуальностью БД, можете просто удалять базу данных с устройства (а не все приложение), будет создана новая. [Как найти БД на устройстве](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/474083/177345)

Comment: Как удалять БД?

Comment: @ЛевПоляков, а зачем ее удалять? Я просто копирую поверх существующей. Ведь БД это обычный файл.

Answer (score 3):

Я делаю так: при установке приложения у меня создается/копируется база данных. В этот момент в Preferences сохраняю код приложения. Если я нее сам позже внес изменения, то так же как и у вас мне ее нужно обновить. Я меняю код приложения и при открытии главной активности делаю проверку текущего кода и сохраненного, если они не совпадают, я копирую/обновляю БД. Ну и снова сохраняю в настройках новый код.

```
public static void checkVersionCode(Context context) {
    boolean flagNewVersion = false;
    int cur_vc = 0;
    try {cur_vc = context.getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(context.getPackageName(), 0).versionCode;
    }catch(NameNotFoundException e) {}

    SharedPreferences mVersion = null;
    try {mVersion = context.getSharedPreferences(VERSION_FILENAME,Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    } catch (Exception e) {
    } finally {
        try {
            if (mVersion.contains(VERSION_CODE)) {
                int pref_vc = mVersion.getInt(VERSION_CODE, 0);
                if (pref_vc != cur_vc) flagNewVersion = true;
            } else flagNewVersion = true;
        } catch (Exception e) {}
    }
    if (flagNewVersion == true) {
        //здесь копируется или обновляется БД
        setVersionCode(context, cur_vc);//сохраняем новую версию
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Если структура БД не меняется то можно просто заливать новую БД в старую, игнорируя одинаковые строки. Для этого новую БД ложим в assets.

У себя в одном проекте сделал так:

```
public DBHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    this.myContext = context;
    create_db();
    dbQueryManager = new DBQueryManager(getReadableDatabase());
    dbUpdateManager = new DBUpdateManager(getWritableDatabase());
    boolean dbexist = checkdatabase();
    if (dbexist) {
        merge_db(DATABASE_VERSION_OLD, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }
}

private boolean checkdatabase() {
    boolean checkdb = false;
    try {
        String myPath = DB_PATH + DATABASE_NAME_OLD;
        File dbfile = new File(myPath);
        checkdb = dbfile.exists();
    } catch (SQLiteException e) {
        System.out.println("Database doesn't exist");
    }
    return checkdb;
}

public void create_db() {
    InputStream myInput = null;
    OutputStream myOutput = null;
    try {
        File file = new File(DB_PATH + DATABASE_NAME);
        if (!file.exists()) {
            this.getReadableDatabase();
            //получаем локальную бд как поток
            myInput = myContext.getAssets().open(DATABASE_NAME);
            // Путь к новой бд
            String outFileName = DB_PATH + DATABASE_NAME;

            // Открываем пустую бд
            myOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);

            // побайтово копируем данные
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            int length;
            while ((length = myInput.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
            }

            myOutput.flush();
            myOutput.close();
            myInput.close();
        }
    } catch (IOException ex) {

    }
}

public void merge_db(int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

    if (newVersion != oldVersion) {
        open();
        database.execSQL("ATTACH DATABASE '" + DB_PATH + File.separator + DATABASE_NAME_OLD + "' AS Old_DB");
        database.execSQL("INSERT OR IGNORE INTO product (title) SELECT task_title FROM Old_DB.product;");
    }
}

public void open() throws SQLException {
    String path = DB_PATH + DATABASE_NAME;
    database = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(path, null,
            SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
}
```

Возможно не совсем правильно но я только начинающий разработчик :)

Answer (score 0):

посмотри на метод onUpgrade (...) SQLOpenHelper'a

этот метод вызывается, если инкрементировать версию БД
здесь можно добавить новые таблицы, модифицировать старые и выполнить миграцию данных из старой версии в новую

Последовательность следующая:

1. Берем данные
2. Модифицируем БД (самый простой вариант удаляем все -> создаем новую структуру)
3. Накатываем данные обратно в новую БД